# Meteor: oncreated vs onrendered

Tags: javascript, meteor, dynamic-arrays

The dilemma:

- **oncreated:** the template is not yet rendered (fires only one
  time for each template).
- **onrendered:** the template is rendered (fires multiple times).

Is it possible to fire a function only once the template is rendered fully?

I have a list of messages, that look similar to this

```
<template name="messages">
    <div id="messages">
        <span class="message">{{this.message}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Each time a new message is inserted into the DOM, I want to know if the text of the message contains the username.

The following code snippet runs multiple times, of which it should only run a single time.

```
Template.messages.rendered = function() {

    var username = Meteor.user().services.twitter.screenName;
    $("#messages").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {    
        var lastmessage = $('.message').last().text();
        if (lastmessage.indexOf(username) > -1) {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Interchanging rendered by created & changing the template to contain a single message, makes the function run one time for each new message. This means it takes the second to last value for the lastmessage variable:

```
Template.message.created = function() {
    var username = Meteor.user().services.twitter.screenName;

    var lastmessage = $('.message').last().text();//this is not the last message
    if (lastmessage.indexOf(username) > -1) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) say that onRendered only fires once: "Callbacks added with this method are called once when an instance of Template.myTemplate is rendered into DOM nodes and put into the document for the first time."

Comment: Well, in my case new messages kept appending into the template and it would be rerendered for each message. Setting a timeout seemed like the only thing that worked, though it may not be in the book of Meteor's best practices.

Comment: @Fullhdpixel it's not a good practice in javascript or any other programming language either, for that case... It's hacking up your code and if you hack your code like this, it's going to become increasingly difficult to maintain such code. You should somehow get to the bottom of the why is your onRendered fired several times.

Comment: also I'm not sure why you're doing this in onRendered/onCreated, but it kinda looks like the proper place for this functionality would be in a helper, but there you have to take into consideration that helpers are called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

Honestly couldn't you do something like this in "rendered".  Or you could put in some callback after you render your extra stuff into the DOM.

Additionally you could use `self.autorun(() => { if(self.alreadyRun) return; ... })` and `self.alreadyRun = new ReactiveVar(false)`.

Just guessing!

```
var self = this;

self.alreadyRun = false;
if(self.alreadyRun){
    self.alreadyRun = true;

    // run once code here

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Fixed this by wrapping the code in a setTimeout function.

Comment: Meteor.defer is also used for the same purpose.